# flutter android studio app unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, sdk

i am a flutter beginner. i face this problem and really i have tried with and i didn't find the solution, the  apk built successfully on android studio and installed on my phone but when i try to open it always i face this problem:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.beauty/com.test.beauty.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.beauty.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~vVpGIeyV47V4c3-Hh5r9Wg==

Comment: try `flutter clean` and run again, if you face any issue, check `flutter doctor`